# Show post categories

Tags: categories, theme-development

I'm trying to show post categories for some breadcrumbs. At the moment, I have this:

```
the_category(' / ', 'multiple');
```

But for some reason, it is stating the parent category twice (I only want `parent > child`):

```
FASHION / DAILY FASHION CANDY / FASHION
```

It should really be:

```
FASHION / DAILY FASHION CANDY
```

Would anyone know why it's doing this, and how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select both categories for the post `the_category()` will display both and using `multiple` will make the child category display the parent relationship, so you will have the parent twice. If you want to display a link to the parent category and a link to child category select only the child category for the post and use `the_category(' / ', 'multiple');`.

Comment: How would I select only the child category for the post — remove the 'fashion' in the categories tickbox?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'single' instead of 'multiple'? (I guess the display of 'multiple' is a bit misleading. In your example I think the first / is a marker for the hiearchy. The second / is for dividing alternatives.)